# hypothesis decorator for inferring all strategies from type hints

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting, python-hypothesis

The Python module hypothesis has a `hypothesis.given` decorator, which allows passing `hypothesis.infer` for individual parameters to derive their strategy from the corresponding type hint. This can be tedious though as all parameters have to be repeated. Here is an example:

```
@given(arg1=infer, arg2=infer, arg3=infer)
def test_something(arg1: int, arg2: bytes, arg3: List[float]) -> None:
    ...
```

The documentation advises that `infer` [is not used by default to retain backwards compatibility](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#hypothesis.infer). Does hypothesis already contain a decorator `given_everything_inferred` that simply assumes `infer` for all arguments or is it easy to write one? Intended usage example:

```
@given_everything_inferred
def test_something(arg1: int, arg2: bytes, arg3: List[float]) -> None:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't provide this by default because it can interfere with things like Pytest fixtures, and the transition to customised strategies (e.g. only positive integers) now requires you to change the whole decorator instead of a single argument.

It's pretty easy to write your own, though:

```py
def given_everything_inferred(func):
    return given(**{n: infer for n in inspect.getfullargspec(func).args})(func)
```

Handling keyword-only arguments, or writing a version which allows you to pass some strategies and infer the rest, is an exercise for the reader ([or sponsorship](https://github.com/sponsors/Zac-HD)).

Comment: It is pretty obvious that such a decorator interferes badly with any other decorator (not limited to pytest). A possible upstream solution would be to recognize typical decorators and obtain the argspec of the decorated function.

Comment: Unfortunately 'unwrapping' doesn't work in general, as the decorator can actually change the argspec - and in fact Hypothesis does just that to ensure that the argspec of the wrapped test matches its actual behaviour.
If you have an example where this has caused problems, that may be worth a bug report.

Comment: I was not proposing a general solution. I think we both agree that there is none. All one can do is special case the unwrapping for a limited number of frequently used decorators. If one uses `functools.wraps` (as most decorators do), the original function can be located by accessing the `__wrapped__` property. Doing that in general is bound to fail, but it could work for a positive list of commonly used decorators.

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate package that does this: [hypothesis-auto](https://timothycrosley.github.io/hypothesis-auto/). It is basically `hypothesis_auto.auto_test`. It has a separate integration into pytest. The link has example uses.